# restriccion al cargar imagen en base de datos mysql -

Tags: php, html, mysqli

quisiera que me ayuden con este código, quiero hacer que mi imagen se guarde como ruta (imagenes/foto.jpg) en la base de datos, pero a la vez me impida que cuando la imagen tenga el peso de mas 2mb no me permita guardalo y me envie un mensaje de advertencia, agradeceria que alguien me ayude con mi codigo, pude agregarlo a mi base de datos pero no puedo restringuir el peso. Gracias de antemano.

```
    <html>
<head></head>
<body>

  <?php
    require('conexion.php');//realizamos la conexion llamando al archivo de conexion

    $dir = "imagenes/"; //recuerda que debe tener permisos de escritura ;)
    $ext = array('image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/jpg'); //Puedes agregar más extenciones

      foreach($_FILES as $archivo) {
        $attachtmp = $archivo['tmp_name'];
        $attachtype = $archivo['type'];
        $attachname = $archivo['name'];


          if(file_exists($attachtmp)) {
          
            if(is_uploaded_file($attachtmp)) {

              if(in_array($attachtype,$ext)) {                

                $ruta = move_uploaded_file($attachtmp, "$dir/$attachname");                
                mysqli_query($conexion,"INSERT INTO imagen (imagen) VALUES ('$dir$attachname')");
              } else {

              echo "Esto no es una imagen :(";
            }
          }
        }

      }

      echo"$dir/$attachname";
  ?>

<form name="subirImagen" method="post" action="prueba3.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p>
<label for="picture">Imagen:</label>
<input type="file" name="imagen" id="picture"/>
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" name="btnSubir" value="Subir imagen"/>
</p>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Agrega a tu formulario `<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000" />` y valida agregando otro if: `if( $archivo['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE )`

Comment: no entendi tu respuesta me podrias graficar en mi codigo!!!